# Angular - provided data source did not match an array, observable, or datasource

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im receiving an object in my component via @Input

**@Input event**

[image]

now I need to use the expenses array on my angular material table.

```
<div class="table-container" *ngIf="event">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="event" class="mat-elevation-z8">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{event.type}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>
</div>
```

But im getting the error:

> provided data source did not match an array, observable, or datasource

Comment: try using `[dataSource]= "event.expenses"`

Comment: @nircraft Thank you !!! Work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `dataSource` supplied to the `mat-table` is not an array because of which you see that error.

The simplest way to provide data to the [`mat-table`](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#1-write-your-mat-table-and-provide-data) is by passing a data array to the table's `dataSource` input.

Since your `expenses` array is in the event object, You need to pass `event.expenses` to table as `dataSource`.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="event.expenses" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

Comment: @HugoSeleiro, Thanks :)